# ShowBalloonTip not working in Windows 1 when it worked it previous editions of WIndows

Tags: vb.net, windows, notifications

Ever since I upgraded to Windows 10, my program refuses to show a notify icon for when an update is released, it worked when I used Windows 7.

This is the code:

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Updates
    Public Sub CheckForUpdates()
        Try
            Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://versionfile.txt"), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

            Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion
            If newestversion > currentversion Then
                CardMaker.NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Update Available!", "Click Here to download it", ToolTipIcon.Info)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An error occured while trying to check for updates:" + vbNewLine + ex.Message + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + ex.ToString, Title:="Error 006")
            My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now this code makes sense, and it works theoretically, but not practically, on windows 10 that is. Problem is, that the program is out there and people may not actually be receiving the notification either if they are using Windows 10.

Is this a known issue? If so, is there a work around to this?

Comment: Anyone? I really need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neve rmind, fixed it. You have to select the notification icon in the visual designer for the balloon tip to show up, although it was defined in the code.